# How to filter a categories query

Tags: craft3, categories, category, filtering, category-filter

I have a categories group named "Title" in my backend. In that group I have 15 categories, but I want to display only 3 specific categories on the frontend. How can I filter my query and display only certain categories?

```
{% for category in craft.categories({ group: 'title', orderBy: 'title asc' }).all() %}
    {{ category.title }} {# will display all the categories but I want to display only 3 specific categories #}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your current query queries for all categories in the category group "title", ordering them by their title.

If you want to list three specific categories, you'll have to create a [categories query](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/categories.html#querying-categories) that filters out all the other categories somehow.

In Craft, most fields can be used to filter element query results. For example, if you wanted to filter by the categories' *title*, you could use the `.title()` param – the below query would only return categories with a title "Foo", "Bar" or "Baz":

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('title').title(['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']).all() %}
```

You can also query by category IDs:

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('title').id([125, 43624, 34]).all() %}
```

Or even by a custom field – for example, assuming you had a Lightswitch field called `featured`, and wanted to query for all categories with this Lightswitch field toggled on:

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('title').featured(1).all() %}
```

Another approach entirely is using a Categories field, to enable authors to select which categories to display. For example, if you created a categories field called `someCategoriesField`, and added it to a global set `someGlobalSet`, you could do this to return any and all categories selected in that field:

```
{% set categories = someGlobalSet.someCategoriesField.all() %}
```

If you want to make sure that only 3 categories are returned, you might also consider adding a `.limit()` parameter to your query:

```
{% set categories = craft.categories.group('title').limit(3).all() %}
```